Wso2 APIM version 4.1.0 CPU resources Usage issue performance tuning
I am facing cpu usage/consumption upto 100% and 100+% as you see the top command response then I tried the tuning document which does not make any affect. Please help to resolve this issue.
here are the dumps and the thread that taking too much cpu 0x334ee at he end of this @updated question.
top - 13:40:47 up 36 days, 22:45,  1 user,  load average: 14.81, 8.55, 4.87
Tasks: 442 total,   1 running, 441 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 42.4 us,  3.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 54.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  86454.3 total,  58039.9 free,  11559.4 used,  16855.1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   4096.0 free,      0.0 used.  74008.5 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
1492023 dts       20   0   33.9g   8.4g  32376 S  1462   9.9 177:43.34 java


I followed the performance tuning document and tried these configurations

* soft nofile 4096
* hard nofile 65535
* soft nproc 20000
* hard nproc 20000
JVM-level settings
-DentityExpansionLimit=10000
WSO2 Carbon platform-level settings
<Valve className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve" 
threshold="500"/> which default 600
API-M-level settings
[passthru_http]
http.socket.timeout=180000
-Xms8192m -Xmx14336m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

%CPU CPU  NI S     TIME     PID     TID

 0.0   -   0 S 00:00:01  209032  210148
15.7   -   0 R 00:28:49  209032  210149
65.9   -   0 R 02:00:56  209032  210150
65.8   -   0 R 02:00:45  209032  210151
21.8   -   0 R 00:40:07  209032  210152
 0.0   -   0 S 00:00:00  209032  210153
19.3   -   0 R 00:35:24  209032  210154
26.0   -   0 R 00:47:40  209032  210155
 0.0   -   0 S 00:00:00  209032  210156
16.0   -   0 R 00:29:27  209032  210157
70.8   -   0 R 02:09:51  209032  210158
 7.4   -   0 R 00:13:39  209032  210159
14.9   -   0 R 00:27:27  209032  210160
 0.0   -   0 S 00:00:00  209032  210161
11.2   -   0 R 00:20:33  209032  210162
23.3   -   0 R 00:42:50  209032  210163


Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu220.04.1 mixed mode):

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x00007fe27c013ca0, length=1456, elements={
0x00007feda83d9800, 0x00007feda83dd800, 0x00007feda83f9000, 0x00007feda83fb000,
0x00007feda83ff800, 0x00007feda8401000, 0x00007feda8403000, 0x00007feda8463000,


"HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-47" #514 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=7776550.97ms elapsed=10986.44s tid=0x00007fe11407d800 nid=0x334ee runnable  [0x00007fde7fc7e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(java.base@11.0.22/HashMap.java:1515)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(java.base@11.0.22/HashMap.java:1534)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:313)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.22/Thread.java:829)


Let's use top -n 1 -H -p  command to check threads that are consuming more CPU. then you can use jstack command to take a few thread dumps and check the problematic thread stack trace.

thanks for helping, but i already take dumps and try to figure out the issue but found nothing when I take usage dump with ps -C java -L -o pcpu,cpu,nice,state,cputime,pid,tid > thread-usage.txt and tried to find that value in jstack  > thread-dump.txt I found no matching related to that value which tid in converted in hexadecimal https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/troubleshooting/admin-troubleshooting-in-production-environments/
by following this link

can you share the dumps and cpu usage report

I have added the dumps in question. @dil
